# C structure uninitialized outside contruction function

Tags: c, pointers, scope, init

I have this 'JobSequence' structure that I wish to instantiate in my main function. To do so I created a `new_JobSequence()` function that allocates the memory and give the proper value to all the fields of the structure. Inside this function, everything is done correctly according to my debugger. But once I go back to my main function `int cost` is set to an arbitrary value, `baseInstance = 0x0` and `list = 0x1`. The address of `jobSequence` before and after `new_JobSequence()` is unchanged and is the same as the one used inside the function.
Here are the declaration of the structure, the code of the function and of main:

```
typedef struct JobSequence{
    Instance* baseInstance;
    List* sequence;
    int cost;
}JobSequence;

void new_JobSequence(Instance* baseInstance, JobSequence* jobSequence){
    jobSequence = malloc(sizeof(JobSequence));
    jobSequence->baseInstance = baseInstance;
    jobSequence->cost = 0;
    list_new(&jobSequence->sequence);
}

int main() {
    int** P = baseInstance();
    Instance instance;
    makeInstanceFromBin(P,10,10,4,&instance);
    printInstance(&instance);
    JobSequence jobSequence;
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
    printf("address : %p\n",&jobSequence);
    new_JobSequence(&instance,&jobSequence);
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
    printf("address : %p\n",&jobSequence);

    Do other stuff (crashes because I try to access the elements of jobSequence which have 0x1 and 0x0 addresses).
}
```

So really I've tried a bunch of stuff but I really can't figure out what's going on here...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
JobSequence jobSequence;
```

You ask the compiler to create a variable of type `JobSequence` on the **stack**.

So *you do not have to reserve memory* by yourself for it.

The problem you face in the debugger is the `jobSequence` in `main` function is not modified by `new_JobSequence` function.

You can see it with some debugging traces:

```
void new_JobSequence(Instance* baseInstance, JobSequence* jobSequence){
    printf("start of %s: js is %p\n", __FUNCTION__, jobSequence);
    jobSequence = malloc(sizeof(JobSequence));

    printf("after malloc, js is %p\n", jobSequence);
    jobSequence->baseInstance = baseInstance;
    jobSequence->cost = 0;
    list_new(&jobSequence->sequence);       
}
```

---

Thus, to make your function work on variable created in `main`, you have to write something like:

```
void new_JobSequence(Instance* baseInstance, JobSequence* jobSequence)
{
    jobSequence->baseInstance = baseInstance;
    jobSequence->cost = 0;
    list_new(&(jobSequence->sequence));
}

...
int main(void)
{
    /* ... */
    JobSequence jobSequence;
    new_JobSequence(..., &jobSequence);
}
```

---

If you want to allocate memory on the **heap** for the structure, you have to follow this approach:

```
JobSequence *new_JobSequence(Instance* baseInstance){
    JobSequence *js= malloc(sizeof *js);
    js->baseInstance = baseInstance;
    js->cost = 0;
    list_new(&(js->sequence));

    return js;
}

...
int main(void)
{
    /* ... */
    JobSequence *jobSequence = new_JobSequence(...);                
}
```

Comment: You need to add a `return js;` in your new_JobSequence()

Answer (score 0):

You have already allocated the instance in your main function. So what you are really doing inside `new_JobSequence()`, is just to allocate some memory in the heap, initialise that and never return anything before exiting from that function. If you want to keep this flow of operation, you need to pass a double pointer into your function (and properly allocate only a pointer in your main function, i.e. `JobSequence *pJobSequence = NULL` ).